# Why does this code not work? errors

Tags: java

```
System.out.print( "Enter an int > " );
int i = scan.nextInt();
while ( i != -1 ) {
    System.out.println( "Hello" );
    System.out.print( "Enter an int > " );
    i = scan.nextInt();
}
```

What is the output of this code assuming the user inputs 3, 5, and -1?
I have tried loading it into multiple editors and trying it out but it keeps giving me errors such as:

```
int i = scan.nextInt ( );
        ^
symbol:   variable scan
```

Comment: Don't post half the error message...

Comment: where scan is declared and initialized ? I `cannot find symbol: variable scan` and so the compiler

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a `Scanner` object before you can use it.

In the very top of the method (I assume main method here), write:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

You'll also need to add an import to the very top of the file:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```